# Dynamic Memory allocation to two dimensional array in C

Tags: c, malloc

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<math.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>  
#include<string.h>  

void allocate_double_2darray(int ip_flag, double **ip_array, int num_row, int num_col); 

int main(void)  
{  

        int num_row, num_col;  
        double **temp_array;  

        num_row = 4;  
        num_col = 2;

        allocate_double_2darray(0, temp_array, num_row, num_col); //Allocate memory
        allocate_double_2darray(1, temp_array, num_row, num_col); //initialize
        allocate_double_2darray(2, temp_array, num_row, num_col); //Free Memory
        return 0;

}

void allocate_double_2darray(int ip_flag, double **ip_array, int num_row, int num_col)  
{  

      int i_loop, j_loop;
      if(ip_flag == 0)  //allocate (free) memeory from array
        { ip_array = malloc(sizeof(double *) * num_row);                   
          for(i_loop = 0; i_loop < num_row; i_loop++)
          ip_array[i_loop] = malloc(sizeof(double) * num_col);                     
        }

      if(ip_flag == 1)  //initialize to zero 
        {    
          for(i_loop = 0; i_loop < num_row; i_loop++)
              for(j_loop = 0; j_loop < num_col; j_loop++)        
                  ip_array[i][j] = 0.0;      
        }   

      if(ip_flag == 2)  //deallocate (free) memeory from array 
        {    
          for(i_loop = 0; i_loop < num_row; i_loop++)
             free(ip_array[i_loop]);
          free(ip_array);         
        }            

}
```

This is the simple function to allocate memory to create two dimensional array. It compiles successfully. However, When i execute it, it gives me segmentation fault error. Does anyone help me to locate what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Wellcome to SO. This seems not to be about a two dimensional array but about an emulation of such a beast. C has 2D arrays directly with language constructs, there is no need to do such complicated stuff. *If* you use `malloc` don't cast its return value. `void*` converts well to any pointer type in C, please have a look into the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the value of a pointer from inside a function. You can use the pointer and change its contents, can't change change the pointer itself and expect it to be available outside.

In your case the call with `ip_flag==0` is not doing anything useful and when it is called with `ip_flag==1` it segfaults.

Possible solutions:

- try using a macro
- or change `ip_array = malloc(sizeof(double *) * num_row);` to the outside of the function `allocate_double2d_array`.

Comment: @RandyHoward: you're right -- fixed it. I just copied from his code to give another alternative fix.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function parameters so it takes a pointer to a matrix, that way you can change where the pointer points to by passing the address of the pointer itself.

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<math.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>  
#include<string.h>  

void allocate_double_2darray(int ip_flag, double **ip_array, int num_row, int num_col); 

int main(void)  
{  

        int num_row, num_col;  
        double **temp_array;  

        num_row = 4;  
        num_col = 2;

        allocate_double_2darray(0, &temp_array, num_row, num_col); //Allocate memory
        allocate_double_2darray(1, &temp_array, num_row, num_col); //initialize
        allocate_double_2darray(2, &temp_array, num_row, num_col); //Free Memory
        return 0;

}

void allocate_double_2darray(int ip_flag, double ***ip_array, int num_row, int num_col)  
{  

      int i_loop, j_loop;
      if(ip_flag == 0)  //allocate (free) memeory from array
        { (*ip_array) = malloc(sizeof(double *) * num_row);                   
          for(i_loop = 0; i_loop < num_row; i_loop++)
          (*ip_array)[i_loop] = malloc(sizeof(double) * num_col);                     
        }

      if(ip_flag == 1)  //initialize to zero 
        {    
          for(i_loop = 0; i_loop < num_row; i_loop++)
              for(j_loop = 0; j_loop < num_col; j_loop++)        
                  (*ip_array)[i][j] = 0.0;      
        }   

      if(ip_flag == 2)  //deallocate (free) memeory from array 
        {    
          for(i_loop = 0; i_loop < num_row; i_loop++)
             free((*ip_array)[i_loop]);
          free((*ip_array));
          (*ip_array) = NULL;         
        }            

}
```